# jQuery touchSwipe content scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, mobile, scroll

I am using jQuery and the touchSwipe plugin to scroll content up and down. I am having some math related issues and wanted to see if the community could quickly help me figure this out.

The touchSwipe "distance" variable returns only positive values starting from zero so the issue comes in to play when the user swipes UP and then decides to swipe DOWN, because the distance values change from ex:(0 initial, 15up, 32up, 20up, 5up, 10down, 40down). I have created 4 if statements to catch all of these situations. How do I handle the "direction change" if statements?

touchSwipe: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/

The swipe up and down function:

```
var _scrolling=false;
var _prev=0;
$("#list").swipe({
  swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, fingerCount) {
    if(phase=="end"){return false;}
    if(phase=="move" && !_scrolling) {
      var t = parseInt($("#list").css("top").split('px')[0]);
      var s = 0;
      if(direction=="up" && (distance-_prev) > 0){
         //still moving up
         s = t-(distance-_prev);
         _prev=distance;
       } else if(direction=="up" && (distance-_prev) < 0){
          //direction change - moving down    
       } else if(direction=="down" && (distance-_prev) > 0){
         //still moving down
          s = t+(distance-_prev);
         _prev=distance;
       } else if(direction=="down" && (distance-_prev) < 0){
          //direction change - moving up
       }
       _scrolling=true;
       $("#list").animate({ top:s }, 70, function() {_scrolling=false;});   
   }<!--if end-->
  }<!--swipeStatus end-->
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few days I was able to solve this issue, revise the original "swipeStatus" function, and create a pretty efficient fully-functional function to scroll an absolute area using the touchSwipe jQuery plugin.

**Solution:**

```
function swipeScroll(c,b,pd,f){
    $(c).swipe({//c style must be position:absolute;top:0; b style must be position:relative;
      swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, fingerCount) {
        if(phase=="start"){pd=0;}
        if(phase=="end"){return false;}
        if(phase=="move" && pd!=distance){
          var t = parseInt($(c).css("top"),10);
          var u = (pd-distance);
          if(direction=="up" && t != u){ t+=u; }else if(direction=="down" && t != -u){ t-=u; }
          pd=distance;
          if(t > 0 || $(b).height() > $(c).height()){t=0;}//top of content
          else if(($(b).height()-t) >= $(c).height()){//bottom of content
            t=$(b).height()-$(c).height();
            if(typeof f != "undefined"){f();}
          }
          $(c).css("top",t);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

**Function parameters explained:**

c: the absolute content you want to scroll
b: the relative container that surrounds the content "c"
pd: variable to store the distanced moved from previous scroll
f: function to call when scroll reaches bottom

Note: "b" must have a relative position and "c" a absolute position with top:0

**Example usage:**

```
var distance;
swipeScroll("#list","#body",distance, function() { alert("bottom"); });
```

**Research:**

Instead of using "$(c).css("top",t);" I also tested this using jQuery animate() function to give the smooth sliding effect but this actually made the scrolling sluggish. An animation gave unexpected results because "t" would sometimes skip "0" when swiped too fast and the direction would change from "top" to "down" causing the content being scrolled to suddenly jump.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Note: using the line

```
if (phase == "end") { return false; }
```

will prevent use of tapping event. So if you need that event, you have to remove this line.